# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Transaction' to System.Collection.GenericList<Transaction>

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class TransactionHistory : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Transaction aTrans = new Transaction();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            bind();
        }
    }
    protected void bind()
    {
        Session["name"] = "John";
        string name = Session["name"].ToString();
        List<Transaction> transList = new List<Transaction>();
        transList = aTrans.getProduct(name);

        gv_Transaction.DataSource = transList;
        gv_Transaction.DataBind();
    }
}
```

i am new in programming. It keeps having error 
and i dont really know how to solve
i am trying to create a dummy data and pass it to the sql so that it displays the entire transaction history.

Comment: What is `GetProduct`? I doubt it returns a `List<Transaction>`.

Comment: assuming it is here:  transList = aTrans.getProduct(name);   and the getProduct is only returning a Transaction, not  a list of Transactions.  So either you need to change your transList to be a single transaction or update your getProduct to return a list

Comment: Can u post the code of `getproduct` method

Comment: GetProduct comes from the method getProduct from the Product cs file

Comment: The question was what it returns, not where it comes from or who created it. Please **show** it.

Comment: how do i post the code here?

Comment: how can i post  the entire code sorry i am new

Comment: By not posting *everything* but just the method. And in there only the *relevant* part, which in your case is its signature and its return-statement(s).

Comment: Given the error I don't think we need to specifically see the getProduct method as it is obviously returning a single transaction. As others have stated that makes the fix just use of list.Add rather than list =

Comment: how do u return a list of transaction from getProduct()

Comment: how do i return a list in the method getProduct @JasperMoneyshot

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace this:

```
transList = aTrans.getProduct(name);
```

with this:

```
transList.Add(aTrans.getProduct(name));
```

The problem is that `getProduct(name)` seems to return a single `Transaction`, but you're trying to assign it to a List of transactions (`List<Transaction>`). You instead need to `Add()` the item to the list.

Comment: or `GetProduct` should return a `List<Transaction>`(a list of all transactions of a given product which means the name should be `GetProductTransactions`).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign the `aTrans.getProduct(name)` to `transList`, when tyou should add the value of `aTrans.getProduct(name)` to the list.

`transList.Add(aTrans.getProduct(name));`

Here is an assumption of how to code should work

```
`class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Transaction aTrans = new Transaction();
            List<Transaction> transList = new List<Transaction>();
            transList.Add(aTrans.getProduct());
        }
    }
    class Transaction
    {
       public string name { get; set; }
        public Transaction()
        {
            name = "name";
        }
        public Transaction getProduct()
        {
            return this;
        }

    }`
```

Comment: Add doesnt exist in current context who do i do next

Comment: @Wen Have you created your own implementation of `List<T>`?

Comment: dont think so @john

Comment: Add is a method on the generic List class, so unless you've created your own implementation of List (which I don't think you've done) then it should be there. It might be worth posting what you've done to replicate this answer on your question above so people can see if there's any errors.

Comment: @kyle Murray how do i modify the getProduct() so that it returns a list of transaction

Comment: @WenXIANG1999 public List<Transaction> getProduct()
        {
            return this;
        }